# Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that under a change of coordinate $$(x,y)\rightarrow (x',y')$$ $$dx'\wedge dy'=J\left | \frac{\partial (x',y')}{\partial (x,y)} \right |dx\wedge dy $$
where, J is a Jacobian of transformation.
I am trying to use the definition of wedge product to prove this result. $$dx\wedge dy=\frac{1}{2}(dx\otimes dy-dy\otimes dx)$$

Comment: Have you tried just to write it out? Follow your nose and I think you'll find it very clear.

Comment: Well, I am actually very new at differential geometry and I am trying to self learn this subject from Isham's book. So, sorry, but I admit that I am pretty much poor at this one.

Comment: If $x' = f(x,y)$ and $y' = g(x,y)$, then $dx' = f_x dx + f_y dy$ and $dy' = ...$; hence $dx \wedge dy = ...$

Comment: Hence, $dx'\wedge dy'=\frac{1}{2}(f_xdx+f_ydy)\otimes (g_xdx+g_ydy)-(g_xdx+g_ydy)\otimes (f_xdx+f_ydy)$ Now, how should I proceed......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up on the comments above, you do know that $dx \wedge dx = dy \wedge dy = 0$ and $dx \wedge dy = - dy \wedge dx$. Hence

$$dx' \wedge dy' = (f_x dx + f_y dy) \wedge (g_x dx + g_y dy) = f_xg_x dx \wedge dx +  f_xg_y dx \wedge dy + ...$$

Now finish the calculation.

Comment: I got $(f_xg_y-f_yg_x)dx\wedge dy$ So,Is $(f_xg_y-f_yg_x)$ called the Jacobian. I thought it's definition was in the form of determinant with partial derivatives in it. Oops sorry, here $f_x$ is the partial derivative, I forgot that. Such a silly mistake to make. Thanks a lot mate !!! You have been a terrific help.